# Creating subscription with Stripe (only for a month)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, subscription

I am creating a first subscription with Stripe (for a Rails app) and I stuck with how long to create a subscription for a month.

Usually, when we create a subscription, it looks like this:

```
Stripe::Customer.create(description:email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
```

This means that for the respective user will be create a subscription where from the user's credit card will be automatically taken every month a respective mount of money.

But some users would like to pay their subscription for example only for a month, which means no recurring billing.

How to do that?

The documentation says that I should set up **cancel_at_period_end** on **true** and then the subscription will end up after the first month (which means that after the first month will be the subscription set up as cancelled).

But where should I set up this parameter?

Or - is my understanding of this problematic wrong and am I overlooking something?

Thank oyu

Comment: (description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token) is a hash... in ruby (and rails) hashes are often used to pass optional parameters... given what you say about the documentation I would guess you should add cancel_at_period_end: true to the hash that is being passed to the create method... i.e. (description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token, cancel_at_period_end: true)

Comment: I've tried this approach, but got an error message that this parameter is unknown for that method.

Comment: I took a look at the docs and it looks like the way you are doing this... the customer will have a list of subscriptions after creation (subscribing them to the plan that was passed)... the attribute cancel_at_period_end appears to be a part of the subscription model... check [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#create_customer) in the explanation of the plan attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the subscriptions using the following code:

```
# Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
# See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_ypuqOnp64ATuGJlbgEwmAtzV"

customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_3R1W8PG2DmsmM9")
customer.subscriptions.retrieve("sub_3R3PlB2YlJe84a").delete
```

By default, the cancellation takes effect immediately. If you would like to cancel the subscription immediately, but keep the subscription active until the end of the billing period (e.g., through the time the customer has already paid for), provide an at_period_end value of true:

```
customer.subscriptions.retrieve("sub_3R3PlB2YlJe84a").delete(:at_period_end => true)
```

In your case, if you wish to provide only one month subscription, you can consider it as one transection, and I would recommend you to do it with `Subscription::Charge` as follows:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :source => token,
  :description => "Example customer"
)

# Charge the Customer instead of the card
Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => 1000, # in cents
    :currency => "usd",
    :customer => customer.id
)
```